# I have written a C++ program to solve sudoku puzzle ,it is showing "Exception has occurred. EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

Here is the code I have written:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int puzzle[9][9]=
{
    {0,5,0,0,6,2,7,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2},
    {7,0,9,3,0,0,0,0,0},
    {3,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0},
    {0,8,0,7,0,9,0,2,0},
    {0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,7},
    {0,0,0,0,0,6,2,0,8},
    {2,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,3,4,2,0,0,9,0},
};//puzzle template

bool row_possible(int row,int number);//To find out whether a number is possible in the particular row

bool column_possible(int column,int number);//To find whether a number is possible in the particular column

bool square_possible(int row,int column,int number);//To find whether a number is possible in its square

bool possible(int row,int column,int number);//To find whether a number is possible in the given position

bool unassigned();//To check whether the puzzle has any unassigned spaces

void printSolution();//To print the final solution to the console

bool solve();//To solve the puzzle

int main()
{
    if(solve())
       printSolution();
    else
       cout<<"\nNo Solution";
return 0;
}
bool row_possible(int row,int number)
{
    int m=0;
    for(int column=0;column<9;column++)
    {
        if(puzzle[row-1][column]==number)
         m++;
    }
    if(m!=0)
        return false;
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}
bool column_possible(int column,int number)
{
    int m=0;
    for(int row=0;row<9;row++)
    {
        if(puzzle[row][column-1]==number)
           m++;
    }
    if (m!=0)
        return false;
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
bool square_possible(int row,int column,int number)
{
    int mod_x=(row-1)%3,mod_y=(column-1)%3;
    int i=(row-1)-mod_x,j=(column-1)-mod_y;
    int m=0;
    int k=0;
    int check_x=3,check_y=3;
    for(k=0;check_x!=0;check_x--)
    {
        for(k=0;check_y!=0;check_y--)
        {
            if(puzzle[i][j]==number)
            m++;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(m!=0)
       return false;
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

bool possible(int row,int column,int number)
{
    if(row_possible(row,number)&&column_possible(column,number)&&square_possible(row,column,number))
        return true;
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
bool unassigned()
{
    int m=0;
    for(int row=0;row<9;row++)
    {
        for(int column=0;column<9;column++)
        {
            if(puzzle[row][column]==0)
               m++;
        }
    }
    if(m>0)
         return true;
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
void printSolution()
{
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
        {
           cout<<puzzle[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }

}
bool solve()
{
    if(!unassigned())
        return true;
    for(int row=1;row<10;row++)
    {
        for(int column=1;column<10;column++)
        {
            for(int number=1;number<10;number++)
            {
                if(possible(row,column,number))
                {
                    puzzle[row-1][column-1]=number;
                    if(solve())
                       return true;
                    puzzle[row-1][column-1]=0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The debugger is throwing the error in:

```
 int m=0;
 int k=0;
 int check_x=3,check_y=3;
```

It says **Exception has occurred.
EXC_BAD_ACCESS**.It also says that read memory is failed.
I dont understand what it says.Let me also know whether my program needs any improvements
Kindly help me.I am using Visual Studio Code on MacOS.Thank You

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The debugger shows the error I mentioned in the above question."Exception has occurred. EXC_BAD_ACCESS" and also "read memory is failed"

Comment: I'm sure your debugger shows much more than that, such as the call stack, and the values of all variables. You will use that information to figure out the reason for the crash; which is very obvious, but you need to learn how to find and fix bugs in your own code. As I mentioned, knowing how to use a debugger is something every C++ developer must know, including me. Also: array indexes in C++ start with 0, not 1. Using 1-based indexing, and manually subtracting 1 each time, is just a breeding ground for bugs. That's one of the bugs here. You should learn how to use 0-based array indexes.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Call Stacks is a bunch of Solve() with pause on exception on top.And in the section which displays the values of the variable,it reads"<read memory from 0x7ffeef3ffffc failed (0 of 4 bytes read)>" for the variables m,k,check_x,check_y.I will look into the indexing of the array.Also can you send links into what call stack means,if possible

Comment: @dejavu So what values to you see for your variables in the debugger when it crashes?

Comment: @john I am seeing the value "<read memory from 0x7ffeef3ffffc failed (0 of 4 bytes read)>" for the variables m,k,check_x,check_y in the function bool square
_possible()

Comment: @dejavu Unfortunately I'm not familar with the debugger you are using. But try going up the call stack and looking at the variables there. At some point you are going to see a variable that has a value it shouldn't have. For instance one of your array index variable will have the wrong value and that is what will have caused the crash. This is what you use a debugger for, to see the state of the program. Don't forget that a debugger is not just for after the program has crashed. You can run your program step by step using the debugger and see what all the values of the variables are as you go.

Comment: @dejavu -- I suggest you rewrite the parts where you are assuming that arrays start at 1.  You have a hodgepodge of 0-based and 1-based indexing going on -- be consistent and make everything 0-based.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I will try

Comment: @john I will try as you say and update here

Comment: you never reset `j` in the loop

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks for finding that out.Now I am convinced that it caused the crash.I will look into solving that and will inform you at the earliest.

Comment: what is the use of `k`? and look at `check_x` and `check_y`

Comment: @rioV8 K has no use,I have removed it in my file, as you said the j was never reset in the loop(I solved it by introducing a temporary variable).And also I found out another mistake too.In Solve(),the before checking the possible(),I have to add"if(puzzle[row-1][column-1]==0)";If this was absent the, the value of the puzzle will alternate between two values.I have corrected them and run my program,it is taking a long time(not showing errors yet) and still waiting for the answer.Can you start a converstion(chat),so we can solve this problem together.

Comment: think again about your algorithm, currently it is **THE** most inefficient way of finding a solution. It can be done in a few microseconds.

Comment: correction at most a few milliseconds

Comment: @rioV8 Why is it the most inefficient algorithm?What should I add/remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple calculation on how long it would take for you to get an answer.

You have 55 open cells that you try 9 different numbers. This gives you 9<sup>55</sup> = 3 * 10<sup>52</sup> tries.

If one try takes 1μs it will take ~ 9.6 * 10<sup>38</sup> **years** to find a solution.

I have written a C++ program and that finds a solution of this sudoku in 30ms and my PC is not a very fast one (5 years old) and 10ms of this is used to print the solution to screen with `printf`

Comment: Thanks I will try to find another optimized algotithm.What do you exactly mean by open cells?

Comment: oh ok you mean zeros.